# Auto resize the width of input text area on hidden DIV

Tags: html, css

I use a Hide/Show .js script that hides some checkboxes and on the right side there is the search field when I click to hide it I want to expand.

Ex.

Before hidding:

[Before hidding Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQoyu.png)

After hidding I want the search field to be expanded 100%

[After hidding Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEpxQ.png)

I searched for 2 days something and can't find a way to make it expand I use the bTemplate engine to store the HTML code.

Comment: width: auto, width: 100%, clear: both: the search field is within TD tag

Comment: That's all you came up with in 2 days?

Comment: I tried different "options" but I forgot, I can post the code maybe someone knows better what I'm missing.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try changing the CSS properties through the "setAttribute" method of the elements in question through Javascript? Basically, the code you used to "hide some of the checkboxes" in the first place is pretty much like how you'd write the code to do the other things you're looking to do.

In other words, When you want the checkboxes out of view and the text entry box centered, as in your second reference pic, you could have the Javascript code written through the "setAttribute" method so that when a particular event happens, the css "display" parameter for the check boxes could be set to "hidden", the size of the text entry box can be increased, and the css "position" parameter for the text entry box can be set to have it centered, etc.

That is, of course if I understand your issue correctly. Can you provide the code you are using? I'm sure me or someone else could clarify things more if we could see what you have written.

Hope that helps at least a little!  :)

Comment: Hey Yupy, sorry I didn't respond back right away. I'm actually new to Stackoverflow and didn't realize that you had commented back. I will give it another spin and see what I can come up with.